# How to change color or customze DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-holo-everywhere

I want to change color of DatePicker that will fit a brand. How I can do that?

Also I want to make in consistent across all verions so I use HoloEverywhere for that. I achieve consistent new UI but now I want to change colors dividers of this custom view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using your own xml. See this blog [post](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html).

I hope this will help you.